# Removing first character in a String leaves whitespace

Tags: python

I have a textfile that looks like this:

```
6 Hello World
```

I'm reading it in as such:

```
with open("test.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        l = line.split(" ")
        print(l)
```

Which prints me the entire string:

```
6 Hello World
```

I want to remove the '6' character, and just store the string 'Hello World' in another string:

I've done this

```
newStr = l.replace(l[0],"")
```

Which now gives me:

```
 Hello World
```

Now I want to remove the leading space, and store the string.
I tried this:

```
newStr2 = newStr.replace(newStr[0],"")
print(newStr2)
```

But this prints:

```
HelloWorld
```

Instead of `Hello World` (no leading space character)
What am I doing wrong here?
Also, using len() on newStr2 tells me the length is 11, even though it's 10. Is len() including a newline character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `newStr.replace(newStr[0],"")` is the same as `newStr.replace(" ","")` which replaces every instance of a single space with an empty string.

What you want is `lstrip` which removes all leading whitespaces  from your string.

More so, to be less verbose, you can simply *slice off* the leading character from the string and then `lstrip`:

```
newStr = l[1:].lstrip()
```

On another note, a new line character is a character of length one and that is properly accounted for in `len`:

```
>>> len('\n')
1
```

---

*Pro-Tip*: `line.split()` does the same and is more efficient than `line.split(" ")`. See [Why is str.strip() so much faster than str.strip(' ')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285654/why-is-str-strip-so-much-faster-than-str-strip)

---

Essentially, your code becomes:

```
with open("test.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        l = line.split()
        print(l[1:].lstrip())
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, if you want to skip the replacing altogether (and assuming that all of your data follows this pattern) is just to take everything from the second element of the list returned by the `.strip()` on, using `join` and slicing, as in:

```
l = " ".join(line.split(" ")[1:])
```